# If branch skipped inside while loop

Tags: java, while-loop

Here is a little game I created for class - works fine except that if guess == number, the message box is NOT displayed, the program skips it and goes to the next message regarding total guesses, etc... something is wrong with my logic, but i am so stuck. i feel like i've tried a million things.. any help please would be so appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class GuessingGameTestMyIdeas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random(); 
        int number = rand.nextInt(32)+1; 

         int guessCount = 0; // total count variable
         int lessCount = 0; //  number of less than guesses
         int moreCount = 0; //  number of greater than guesses

         String guessString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess the number I'm thinking of, between 1 and 32: ");
         int guess = Integer.parseInt(guessString) ;  

         while (guess != number){  //run this loop while guess is not equal to the random number generated.
             if (guess == number){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You guessed correctly");
             } else if (guess < number){
                 lessCount = lessCount + 1;
                 String lowString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your guess is too low. Next Guess:");
                 guess = Integer.parseInt(lowString); 
             } else { 
                 moreCount = moreCount +1;
                 String highString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your guess is too high. Next Guess:");
                 guess = Integer.parseInt(highString);

             }
             guessCount += 1; // after each guess, the guessCount goes up by one
         }    

         String output = "Your total number of guesses is " + guessCount + " with " + lessCount + " smaller guesses " + moreCount + " larger guesses.";
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
```

Comment: Have you tried to step through the code using a debugger? If you'd do that you'd see that if `guess == number` the loop would quit and the `if` statement wouldn't be executed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move the line

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You guessed correctly");
```

behind the while loop.

Or move the if at the end of the while loop, but the first option seems clearer to me.

The condition of you while loop is `guess != number` and directly after it you ask for `guess == number`. Thus this will never be true. When the player has guessed right, the loop is left and the if claus is not evaluated again.

BTW: debugging your program would have shown you that.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. i kind of thought of that, and tried to put it ABOVE the while loop, which didn't work, so i threw that idea out, upon reading your reply i put it BELOW the while loop and it works! thank you and thank you for the debugging tip, however i did try the debugger and it didn't tell me. but i am only 3 weeks into learning java so i could have screwed that up too... much thanks

Comment: Great! Now you can upwoting the answers which were helpful to you and accept one of the answers / the most helpful one. Then the question is closed and it is indicated that you have been helped.

Answer (score 0):

Keep below lines outside while loop.

```
if (guess == number){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You guessed correctly");
}
```

I hope it helps !!

Comment: Thank you Sanket! Helped beautifully!